# Корректное сохранение/использования числа HEX

Tags: java, android, hex

Получаю число на входе (int) в hex 
например 0xff6699ff
но если я его, например, читаю через 
System.out.println(0xff6699ff);

то вместо ожидаемого 4284914175 в десятичной системе,
я получаю -10053121

Как мне получить корректное отображение?

Comment: Мне надо ArrayList<Integer> hexColors; где я смогу хранить полученные значения (цвета) и затем их снова использовать. Спасибо вам за помощь.

Comment: стоит ли заморачиваться - значение числа остаётся правильным: `System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(-10053121));
 //вывод: ff6699ff`

Comment: Да, действительно заморачиваться не стоит, я уже понял. Ошибка оказалась в другом, причем очень глупая) Но я был уверен, что проблема именно в том что я неправильно сохраняю данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для хранения этих чисел используйте тип `long`. Тип `int` вмещает максимальное значение `2147483647`, а вам этого не хватает. Происходит переполнение и число становится отрицательным.

Если вы добавите в конец числа литеру `L`, то вывод будет верным.

```
System.out.println(0xff6699ffL);
```

Соответственно, ваш список должен состоять из объектов класса `Long`:

```
ArrayList<Long> hexColors;
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Число hex, преобразованное в int, именно так и выглядит.

Вероятно, вы хотите перевести hex в беззнаковое 32-битное число — тип long.

Comment: По сути я хочу, в случае надобности хочу быть готовым отправить сохраненный и полученный 0xff6699ff, а для этого надо правильно сохранить. Если подскажете , или дадите ссылку грамотную буду рад.

Comment: Используйте тип long. Он обычно нативно переводится из/в hex.

Comment: Не сочтите за наглость просьбу предоставить пример...